# filtration generated by process $S_t=S_0 \exp \left(\mu t-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t+\sigma W_t\right)$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

$W_t$ - Wiener process and $(F_t^W)$ its natural filtration.

$$S_t=S_0 \exp \left(\mu t-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t+\sigma W_t\right)$$

where $S_0,\sigma>0, \mu\in\mathbb{R}$, $(F_t^S)$ - natural filtration of process $(S_t)$. Prove that $F_t^S=F_t^W$ for every $t\ge0$

how to prove it?

$\sigma\left\{S_s:0\le s\le t\right\}=\sigma\left\{S_0 \exp \left(\mu s-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}s+\sigma W_s\right):0\le s\le t\right\}$ and what next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$W_t=\frac{1}{\sigma }\left( \ln(S_t)-\ln(S_0)-\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma ^2}{2} \right)t\right).$$

Comment: so you calculated $W_t$ from equality $S_t=S_0 \exp \left(\mu t-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t+\sigma W_t\right)$ but I don't quite understand how to use it :( $\sigma\{W_t\}=\sigma\{\frac{1}{\sigma }\left( \ln(S_s)-\ln(S_0)-\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma ^2}{2} \right)s\right): 0\le s\le t.\} $and insert here $S_s=S_0 \exp \left(\mu s-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}s+\sigma W_s\right)$? It makes sense?

Comment: @TuptuśTupta: Not really... Notice that $\sigma (X)=\{f(X)\mid f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\text{ a Borel function}\}.$

Comment: kill me but I don't know how to solve it. Could you put the full answer? I guess the task is not difficult but I would like to see how it works on the example solved

Comment: Set $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma }(\ln(x)-\ln(y)-(\mu-\sigma ^2/2)t$. This function is continuous on $\mathbb R^+\times \mathbb R^+$ and thus, it's a Borel function. Now, for all $u\leq t$, you have that $$W_u=f(S_u,S_0)\in \sigma (S_u,S_0)\subset \sigma (S_t\mid t\leq u)=\mathcal F_t^S.$$ Therefore $\mathcal F^W_t\subset  \mathcal F_t^S$.

Comment: there should be$ \sigma (S_u\mid u\leq t)$ instead of $\sigma (S_t\mid t\leq u)$ right?

Comment: @TuptuśTupta: Yes you right. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: and why are we considering the functions of 2 variables? Can't be $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma }(\ln(x)-\ln(S_0)-(\mu-\sigma ^2/2)t$ and then $W_u=f(S_u)\in \sigma (S_u)\subset \sigma (S_u\mid u\leq t)=\mathcal F_t^S.$ since $S_0$ - constant? 

And in the other way it will be similarly with $f(x)=S_0 \exp \left(\mu t-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t+\sigma x\right)$?

Comment: I thought that $S_0$ was a positive r.v. But if it's a constant, then you are right. I didn't understand your last question.

Comment: We show that $\mathcal F^W_t\subset  \mathcal F_t^S$ so now we have to show that $\mathcal F^S_t\subset  \mathcal F_t^W$. So its the same way to prove it and we only change function to $f(x)=S_0 \exp \left(\mu t-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t+\sigma x\right)$?

Comment: yes, exactly. $ \ \ $

Comment: uff thank you so much for help :)